# Combining .txt files

Tags: c#, performance

A guy at the company I work for needed a small application that would combine multiple text files into one, larger text file.

I wrote a console application for this. it seems pretty efficient, but I was wondering if there would be an even more efficient way of doing this.

It has 2 important functions, one that gets the files from a folder, where `string input` is the folder location:

```
static string[] getFiles(string input)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@input);

    FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach(FileInfo file in files)
    {
        list.Add(input + @"\" + file.Name);
    }

    string[] arr = list.ToArray();
    return arr;
}
```

And of course the function that combines the files together, its input are the name of the file (`string newName`) and an array with the names of the files found in the folder by `getFiles()` (`string[] files`):

```
static void writeDump(string newName, string[] files)
{
    if (!File.Exists(newName))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(newName))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(files[i]))
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("File already exists");
        start(); //start is called from the main function
    }
}
```

And because `start();` might be confusing, I'll also add the main function here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    start();
}
```

How efficient is this and could it be more efficient?

Comment: I don't think it can be any more efficient then with using streams. It can only be prettier but for a quick&dirty tool this is quite good.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `cat` from the console?

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble what do you mean with `cat`?

Comment: @Grey i mean the unix command line utility `cat` which concatenates files together. Here is the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat)

Comment: Cat also works in Windows. Sounds like you're already working from a command prompt. You/he could do `cat path/to/files/*.txt > my_output_file.txt` instead of writing a program. But writing programs is fun/learning ;-)

Comment: the reason I did this is becaut It's relatively very time consuming to concatenate 4 huge text files together, while this program does it in less than a second :D @DavidBenKnoble

Comment: @brian_o I agree; just saving the reinvention of wheel time. Ironically, reinventing wheels is very fun for me

Comment: @Grey I just timed how long it takes to make a 1GB text file. 12 seconds for your program, 12 seconds for `cat`. I'm not trying to discourage you, but I don't think you should get the idea that using C# is going to result in way less time consuming operations as compared to basic shell commands. Unless you're addressing some kind of edge case (4 files that concatenate in less than a second probably doesn't qualify).

Comment: @brian_o I've never tried `cat`, the person I made this for just wanted this because it would be easy to use, you wouldn't let someone manually copy and paste those files into one, right? that's what the guy would do, and he's not much of a PC guy, just wants stuff to work you know? :P maybe I'm reïnventing the wheel, I probably am, but this was very fun to work on, I would've had a very very very boring day otherwise xD also, yay, statistics about programming related stuff :D I love that :D

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble, yes. As explained at moderate length in my answer, text encodings mean that byte-level concatenation doesn't always give the right output, *especially* in a Windows environment because MS used to be quite keen on UTF-16 and is still keen on putting a BOM at the start of UTF-8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
>         list.Add(input + @"\" + file.Name);
> ```

Seems a bit pointless: [`file.FullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) would get you the fully qualified name without throwing information away and reconstructing it. In fact, that method could be simplified with Linq to

```
static string[] getFiles(string input)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@input);
    return dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt").Select(f => f.FullName).ToArray();
}
```

I also note that the .Net convention for the name would be `GetFiles` with an initial uppercase letter.

---

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
> {
>     using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(files[i]))
>     {
>         string s = "";
>         while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
>         {
>             sw.WriteLine(s);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Since you don't care about `i` you could simplify things with `foreach`; and the initial value of `s` is unnecessary, so you could have

```
foreach (var filename in files)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filename))
    {
        string s;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

But now we get to two key points of the requirements which aren't explicitly stated:

1. If the files don't end with newlines, this code will insert newlines. That may or may not be intended, and it may or may not be desirable.
2. This code is using an `Encoding` to parse the bytes to strings, then using an `Encoding` to convert the strings back to bytes. The particular encoding used is implicit. This isn't particularly efficient, but it does have some benefits:

   - If the files were generated by Microsoft tools, they are quite likely to start with BOMs (even if they're UTF-8). In the nasty case that they mix UTF-8-BOM, UTF-8, and UTF-16 then you rely on the encoding conversion.
   - Even if the files are consistent, you're going to avoid the appearance of BOMs embedded in the text that a straightforward byte-by-byte concatenation would give.

   It also has at least one non-performance-related disadvantage:

   - Regardless of the encoding of the input files, the output file is likely to be UTF-8-BOM, which may be an undesirable side-effect if they were all UTF-8 or UTF-16.

If you wanted a straight byte-by-byte conversion then it would be more efficient to use

```
using (var strmOut = File.Create(newName))
{
    foreach (var filename in files)
    {
        using (var strmIn = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            strmIn.CopyTo(strmOut);
        }
    }
}
```

If you can guarantee that the input files are all UTF-8-BOM then it would be more efficient to use

```
using (var strmOut = File.Create(newName))
{
    foreach (var filename in files)
    {
        using (var strmIn = File.OpenRead(filename))
        {
            strmIn.Position = 3;
            strmIn.CopyTo(strmOut);
        }
    }
}
```

although that's not production-quality code (should check that there are 3 bytes and that they correspond to a BOM).

Comment: thanks, I've adjusted (most of) my code to your suggestions, though I've left the file streams in, since the txt files are all UTF-8 BOM, and the file stream make it a bit easier for me to read, and isn't impacting the preformance that much, I think, might be wrong... and indeed, the convension for .NET is to use capitalcase functions, but I've always felt that was just for classes :) thanks for the suggestions, much apriciated

Comment: If you just need the name then Directory is more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

Some quick remarks:

- Method names should be PascalCase: `getFiles`, `writeDump`, `start`.
- Use descriptive variable/parameter names: `input` doesn't tell me anything. Ditto `newName`, especially since that looks like it is a **path** and not just a name.
- Don't do this: `input + @"\" + file.Name`. This is why `Path.Combine()` exists.
- Why use `DirectoryInfo` when `Directory.GetFiles` exists? Matter of fact, all of `getFiles` can be replaced by that!
- Why use `for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)` when `foreach(var filePath in files)` would be so much easier and clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Minor but you are creating an `FileInfo[] files` when you could just process them.

You could do the names and text in one loop.

Return List.  The consumer can cast to an array if they need to.

```
public static void ListTextPlus(out List<string> fileNames, string outFile, string dirName = @"c:\temp\")
{
    fileNames = new List<string>();
    string line;

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);

    if (di != null && di.Exists)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(outFile))
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
            {
                fileNames.Add(dirName + @"\" + fi.FullName);
                using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
                {
                    //all text would be more efficient but line by line is lower memory
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                            sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
                sw.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered saying something about this but didn't. IMO there is a slight documentation advantage to explicitly working with an eager sequence of input filenames, and that's that it avoids the need to think "*If my output filename matches the wildcard, could anything go wrong?*"

Comment: @PeterTaylor You also get a (very) slight advantage of .OpenText method